# What does it really mean by "Kafka partitions are immutable"?

Tags: apache-kafka, offset, partition

In all the Kafka tutorials I've read so far they all mentioned "Kafka partitions are immutable". However, I also read from this site https://towardsdatascience.com/log-compacted-topics-in-apache-kafka-b1aa1e4665a7 that from time to time, Kafka will remove older messages in the partition (depending on the retention time you set in the log-compact command). You can see from the screenshot below that data within the partition has clearly changed after removing the duplicate Keys in the partition:

[image]

So my question is what exactly does it mean to say "Kafka partitions are immutable"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tha Kafka partitions are defined as "immutable" referring to the fact that a producer can just append messages to a partition itself and not changing the value for an existing one (i.e. with the same key). The partition itself is a commit log working just in append mode from a producer point of view.
Of course, it means that without any kind of mechanisms like deletion (by retention time) and compaction, the partition size could grow endlessly.
At this point you could think .. "so it's not immutable!" as you mentioned.
Well, as I said the immutability is from a producer's point of view. Deletion and compaction are administrative operations.
For example, deleting records is also possible using the Admin Client API ... but we are always talking about administrative stuff, not producer/consumer related stuff.

If you think about compaction and how it works, the producer initially sends, for example, a message with key = A and payload = "Hello". After a while in order to "update" the value, it sends a new message with same key = A and payload = "Hi" ... but actually it's a really new message appended at the end of the partition log; it will be the compaction thread in the broker doing the work of deleting the old message with "Hello" payload leaving just the new one.
In the same way a producer can send the message with key = A and payload = null. It's the way for actually deleting the message (null is called "tombstone"). Anyway the producer is still appending a new message to the partition; it's always the compaction thread which will delete the last message with key = A when it saw the tombstone.

Comment: I see. @ppatierno, so if I understand correctly "immutable partition" refers to the content within each message in the partition won't change. But older messages could get deleted to make way for new messages in the active segment and that's fine. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: I would say yes

Answer (score 2):

Inidividual messages are immutable.

Compaction or retention will drop messages. It doesn't alter messages or offsets

Answer (score 2):

Data in Kafka is stored in topics, topics are partitioned, each partition is further divided into **segments** and finally each segment has a log file to store the actual message, an index file to store the position of the messages in the log file and timeindex file, for example:

```
$ ls -l /mnt/data/kafka/*consumer*/00000000004618814867*
-rw-r--r-- 1 kafka kafka 10485760 Oct  3 23:41 /mnt/data/kafka/__consumer_offsets-7/00000000004618814867.index
-rw-r--r-- 1 kafka kafka  8189913 Oct  3 23:41 /mnt/data/kafka/__consumer_offsets-7/00000000004618814867.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 kafka kafka 10485756 Oct  3 23:41 /mnt/data/kafka/__consumer_offsets-7/00000000004618814867.timeindex
```

In scenario where `log.cleanup.policy` (or `cleanup.policy` on particular topic) set to *delete*, occur complete delete some of log segments (one or more).

In scenario where params set to *compact* the compaction is done in the background by periodically **recopying** log segments: it recopies the log from beginning to end removing keys which have a later occurrence in the log. New, clean segments are swapped into the log immediately so the additional disk space required is just one additional log segment (not a fully copy of the log). In other words, the old segment is replaced by a new compacted segment

See more about distributed logs:

https://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#compaction

https://medium.com/@durgaswaroop/a-practical-introduction-to-kafka-storage-internals-d5b544f6925f

https://engineering.linkedin.com/distributed-systems/log-what-every-software-engineer-should-know-about-real-time-datas-unifying

https://bookkeeper.apache.org/distributedlog/docs/0.5.0/user_guide/architecture/main

https://bravenewgeek.com/building-a-distributed-log-from-scratch-part-1-storage-mechanics/

Answer (score 1):

Immutability is a property of the records stored within the partitions themselves. When the source (documentation or articles) states immutability within the context of topics or partitions, they are usually referring to either one of two things, both of which are correct in a limited context:

1. **Records are immutable**. Once a record is written, its contents can never be altered. A record can be deleted by the broker when either (a) the contents of the partition are pruned due to the retention limit, (b) a new record is added for the same key that supersedes the original record and compaction takes place, or (c) a record is added for the same key with a `null` value, which acts as a tombstone record, deleting the original without adding a replacement.
2. **Partitions are append-only from a client's perspective**, in that a client is not permitted to modify records or *directly* remove records from a partition, only append to the partition. This is somewhat debatable, because a client can induce the deletion of a record through the compaction feature, although this operation is asynchronous and the client cannot specify precisely which record should be deleted.